# Confusion about GISTIC threshold

Tags: wgs, cnv

Please, can you help me with a confusion?

In whole genome sequencing, if

`Total copy number (major + minor allele copy number by SCAT R package)` for SMAD4 in a sample = `4`

Th estimated `ploidy` by SCAT for this sample = `4.043696`

So, the `segment mean` (required for GISTIC) for SMAD4 for this given position of genome in the given sample = log2(4`/`4.043696) =  `-0.01567461`

We can consider this as a `loss of copy number` for SMAD4

But with `GISTIC threshold -td = 0.1` this is neutral copy number change (if I am not wrong)

So, If I want to ask GISTIC to give me

```
amplification: copy number ≥2 × average ploidy​
gain:  copy number >1.25 × average ploidy
loss: copy number <0.75 ×average ploidy
deletion: copy number 0
```

If I put `-ta = 1.25` and `-td = 0.75` , do I achieve the above?

I am seriously struggling with this intuition of relationship between segment mean and GISTIC copy number threshold

Thank you for any help

Comment: You've invested quite the effort in this question, Angel. I hope this gets answered soon and answered well. Cheers!